# FFMPEG: How to convert M2V Video with two single WAV tracks (stereo) to MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, wav, mpeg

How can I create a MP4 file with ffmpeg out of a M2V-Video-File and two WAV-Files (one file for the right audio channel and one for the left audio channel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.m2v -i audio1.wav -i audio2.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

I believe `mp4` files cannot contain PCM audio, hence converting to `aac`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!!
Can I ask you for 2 more things?

1) How would it be done in case of just one wav file (mono)?
2) would you mind explaining your command?

Comment: @jimmy88 for one wav file, this should do it: `ffmpeg -i video.m2v -i audio1.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4` and [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) are some docs that can explain better than I can. also, could you please click to accept this answer?